# Access denied for user when using real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to use mysql_real_escape_string() to secure a log in form.

Using this code:

```
include_once 'access-shared.php';
include_once 'access-databaseconnect.php';
session_start();
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['email'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : $_SESSION['email'];
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['password'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) : $_SESSION['password'];
```

Trouble is it throws up an error every time:

`Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I can't get my head around it, the db user has all permissions and the username details are correct in the access-databaseconnect.php file. It works perfectly without the mysql_real_escape_string around the $_POST but obviously it leaves it open to mySQL injection.

Any help is most appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the contents of the access-databaseconnect.php file:

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'xxxx';
$dbpassword = 'xxxx';

function dbConnect($db='') {
    global $dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword;

    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword)
        or die('Cannot connect to Database:  '.mysql_error());

    if ($db!='' and !@mysql_select_db($db)) 
        die('Cannot connect to Database:  '.mysql_error());
    return $dbcnx;
}
?>
```

Comment: Post the contents of `access-databaseconnect.php`

Comment: The statements for the connection are in one of the two included files?

Comment: You definitely need to remove those `isset()`s from inside the parameters

Comment: I have edited my original question with the access-databaseconnect.php contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, you must have already established a connection via `mysql_connect()`.  If that does not occur in `access-databaseconnect.php`, or the connection has not succeeded, you will not be able to call `mysql_real_escape_string()`

**Update**

You define the function `dbConnect()` in access-databaseconnect.php, but you never call it. Create your connection as

```
$dbcnx = dbConnect($dbname);
```

An additional note, but not the source of your problem... Do not call `mysql_real_escape_string()` around the result of your `isset()` calls. Though it is most likely harmless, it is unnecessary.

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['email'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : $_SESSION['email'];
// Should be
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : $_SESSION['email'];
```

Comment: Yes it does use mysql_connect() in the access-databaseconnect.php file:  $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword)
        or die('Cannot connect to Database:  '.mysql_error());

Comment: @NoahGoodrich remove the `@` from `mysql_connect()` to see if any warnings are being issued.

Comment: @NoahGoodrich You never called your function `dbConnect()`

Comment: Where do I add $dbcnx = dbConnect($dbname); in the code I posted above?